# Drastic (promotional) design changes within the same website; recommendations on points to make to push back?

Tags: usability, users, marketing, experience

Am getting brought into a discussion where a Marketing team wants to have a big dedicated page with completely different branding colors to promote one section of a website (bold blacks and garish wood paneling background) that doesn't go with the rest of our basic but clean eCommerce website at all.

I'm concerned about the abrupt nature of the transition will elicit a "What the hell?" impact with the users to the point they'd wonder if they're even on the same site -- potentially disrupting our checkout funnels and everything else.

If we do what they want I'd almost prefer going to a microsite (and that is one avenue I could advocate for); but does anyone have any points I could make to argue against disrupting the UX in favor of a marketing blitz for one specific underperforming product if I do have to house the content on the parent site?

Suggestions appreciated--

Comment: what are marketing's reasons for it?

Comment: They want the site to match more closely a static print brochure campaign...but they are talking about actually an entirely different site design for this one area (losing all navigation consistency, etc)

Comment: If the print brochure has info to access this landing page and is the only way to access this landing page (meaning user can't stumble upon this page while browsing the regular site), I do not see a reason why it shouldn't match in style to the brochure since the landing page's theme matches the brochure's theme.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really the scenario. This is within a much larger site and isn't being sent with a URL in a mailer or something. They just want their area to POP and design their own thing. I guess maybe it's not a great question for this forum but I'd like some sensible ammunition I might not have thought of if I can get it...

Comment: here are some resources that you could use: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/cross-channel-consistency/

Comment: #8 in this article as well: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-mistakes-web-design/

Comment: Is the brochure already done/printed? If so, at least it's a temporary issue & you can always revert later - it'll probably look like an advertisement & draw even less attention than normal, so maybe it'll be a good case study... If not yet printed, does your company have any branding/style guidelines you can refer to? Marketing ought to understand the importance of maintaining brand identity over short-term promotions.

Answer (score 1):

**Cross Channel Consistency is a problem that plagues many companies.** There have been numerous studies and write-ups from NN/g, UX Mag and even CMO.com on the issue.

I suggest checking out these links and sharing them with the team:
http://www.nngroup.com/articles/cross-channel-consistency/
http://www.cmo.com/articles/2014/4/17/cross_channel_consis.html

Remember, even a microsite should maintain some form of branding consistency. So no matter the path, it's best to ensure your messaging, branding, and story are all in line.

Best of luck.